# Formula evaluation not working in NPOI 2.1.3.0

Tags: c#, excel, formula, npoi

I am creating an Excel workbook in code behind and save it as both XLSX and PDF. I use a template workbook for this that has formatting and formulae to be evaluated after the generating is done. When I open the Excel file, the formulae evaluate only when I set `ForceFormulaRecalculation` to true. When I do the same with the PDF file, I get `#VALUE!` where the results should be. My relevant code:

```
ReportGenerator generator = new ReportGenerator();
List<Activity> activities = GetActivitiesForItemCollection(items);

generator.CreateWorkbook(templatePath);

generator.Year = int.Parse(year);
generator.Month = int.Parse(month);

activities = generator.SortActivitiesByDateTime(activities);

activities = generator.GenerateBreaksForProject(activities);
bool isExternalReport = false;

if (project == "Intern")
    isExternalReport = true;

generator.GenerateReports(activities, isExternalReport);

if (pdf && !xlsx)
    generator.SaveReportToList(OutputFileType.PDF, generator.AssembleFileName(UserProperties.FullName, project, month, year, OutputFileType.PDF));
else if (xlsx && !pdf)
    generator.SaveReportToList(OutputFileType.XLSX, generator.AssembleFileName(UserProperties.FullName, project, month, year, OutputFileType.XLSX));
else
{                            
    generator.SaveReportToList(OutputFileType.XLSX, generator.AssembleFileName(UserProperties.FullName, project, month, year, OutputFileType.XLSX));
    generator.SaveReportToList(OutputFileType.PDF, generator.AssembleFileName(UserProperties.FullName, project, month, year, OutputFileType.PDF));
}
```

Here is my code where I do the evaluation:

```
public void SaveReportToList(OutputFileType outputType, string filename)
{
      string siteUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
      SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
      {
           using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
                sheet.PrintSetup.Landscape = true;
                sheet.PrintSetup.FitWidth = 1;
                sheet.PrintSetup.FitHeight = 1;

                XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
                workbook.Write(mStream);

                using (MemoryStream crutchStream = new MemoryStream(mStream.ToArray()))
                {
                    using (SPSite spsite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb spweb = spsite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                           ....
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
private void ForceCalculateSheet()
{
      XSSFFormulaEvaluator helper = (XSSFFormulaEvaluator)workbook.GetCreationHelper().CreateFormulaEvaluator();

      for(int i = 0; i<sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
      {
          XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);

          for(int j = 0; j< row.LastCellNum; j++)
          {
               XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell)row.GetCell(j);

               if(cell != null && cell.CellType == CellType.Formula)
               {
                   helper.EvaluateFormulaCell(cell);
               }
          }
     }
 }
```

Here are a couple of formulae I try to evaluate (some of the cell values are 24-hour time values):

```
=IF(D37-C37-E37>0;D37-C37-E37;0)
=INT(J39/60)
=J39-C39*60
```

The weird thing is, when I trace the evaluation in Excel, it goes through until the last step. Then suddenly the value becomes `#VALUE!`.

Anybody got an idea what's going on here?

---

Just to be careful, I updated NPOI to it's latest .NET Version (2.1.3.1). This still didn't fix the problem.

When I click a cell that's in the formula, change its value, then confirm it with pressing Enter, the formula evaluates correctly. Meaning there shouldn't be anything wrong with the formulae themselves.

I solved it by manually doing the calculations. This isn't my long-term solution as users should be able to insert their own calculations, but it's the only solution I can come up with right now besides using another Excel framework (bad planning ;)).